# Laravel Not Accessing The Request of data post

Tags: php, laravel-5

Here I create a form in Laravel to post request through route "posts.store" to the controller "PostsController"

```
        {!! Form::open(['url' => 'posts.store']) !!}
            {{Form::Label('title','Title:')}}
            {{Form::Text('title',null,array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
            {{Form::Label('body','Post Body:')}}
            {{Form::Textarea('body',null,array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
            {{Form::Submit('Create Post',array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block','style' => 'margin-top:20px;'))}}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is the "PostsController" where I am trying to access my request which throughs an error:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //validate data
        $this-> validate($request, array(
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'body'  => 'required'

            ));
        //Store data into database
        $post = new Post;

        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->body = $request->body;
        $post->save();

        return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
    }
```

When I submit the form the following page is appearing

**NotFoundHttpException:**

[image]

Comment: what do you have in your route can you show us

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'posts.store']) !!}
```

to this:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'PostController@store']) !!}
```

To get PostData you need this:

```
$postData = $this->request->all();
$post->title = $postData['title'];
$post->body = $postData['body'];
```

Comment: After applying both the changes still get an error named                       
(1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException

at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'))
in RouteCollection.php (line 238)

Comment: you need to add method POST inside route

Comment: I used this 
Route::resource('posts','PostsController');
because i have to use all the resources togather

Comment: still not working but when i tried to separate my routes like this Route::post('posts/store','PostsController@store');
Route::get('posts/show','PostsController@show'); then the data is inserted into database with error in redirection  return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);   error: Route "posts.show" not defined

Answer (score 0):

In your NotFoundException screenshot you can see the URL it is going to is http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts.store obviously this is not going to work. Change the         `{!! Form::open(['url' => 'posts.store']) !!}` to `Form::open(['action' => 'PostsController@store', 'method' => 'POST'])`. Also, make sure your POST route is setup in web.php.